# Wrong formatting when using print in awk

Tags: awk

I have a 2 column file that come from http://snap.stanford.edu/data/cit-HepPh.html. The file I downloaded is *cit-HepPh.txt.gz*. I delete all characters that are not numbers (the first 4 lines of the file), then I change the tab space between numbers with a simple space with:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' Cit-HepPh.txt > 1
```

Then I tried to reverse the elements in the file and write them in another file. I used

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' 1 > 2
```

but what I obtain is something like

```
2
 1
3 
 2
5
 4
...
```

Instead of something like

```
2 1
3 2
5 4
...
```

why?

---

I did

```
head -2 Cit-HepPh.txt | od -a
```

and I have in return

```
0000000   9   9   0   7   2   3   3  ht   9   3   0   1   2   5   3  cr
0000020  nl   9   9   0   7   2   3   3  ht   9   5   0   4   3   0   4
0000040  cr  nl
0000042
```

what does it means?

Comment: Not possible with the input as shown, check your input files and output file carefully. What linestyle endings is your input file. Run it thought `dos2uxix`.

Comment: perhaps it is a line ending issue or other non-printing characters in the file ?

Comment: with this example it works.. but with the file I have, that is really big, it does not... don't know why..

Comment: Great, how is the helpful to anyone!? Don't waste peoples time, post your **actual** question.

Comment: @sudo_O I made all the possible edit. I hope that the problem is now clear.. Sorry for the "first" question.

Comment: Did you try un-gzipping the file first? Your problem is control characters in the file, not awk.

Comment: Yes, I have unzzipped the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like there are some other (non-printing) characters in your file

try to post the output of

```
head -2 Cit-HepPh.txt | od -a
```

the head will take the first two lines of input od will print each character (or its code if it is non printing)

If you identify the problem, you can remove the offending charaters with sed or awk

**edit**

You have cr nl as the line ending (i.e. dos line endings) to you need to strip them with something like dos2unix, or you can do in awk something like

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"");print $2,$1}'
```

Comment: I edited the question with the output generated by the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this:

```
$ cat in.txt 
1 2
2 3
4 5
$ awk '{print $1,$2}' <in.txt
1 2
2 3
4 5
```